# JSON image to sqlite Android programming

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I am new to Android Programming and would like to ask about JSON/sqlite. I have already parsed JSON text and store it in sqlite and then displayed the data in a listview in my app. However, I didn't parse the images in my JSON file (started with the easy part first). Now I have to do the image parsing and I have looked through many websites but still feel too confused about how to do it. 
In the following link 
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/
I have looked at how they do the image parsing but they're caching the images while I have to store the data into DB. In the link there is ImageLoader.java, MemoryCache.java, FileCachee.java,and Utils.java; these classes made me even more confused, do I need all of these for the images? 
Can anyone please guide me like what steps I should follow? which classes of these do I need and which are not necessary?Or any kind of help.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

To read in a single image, no you don't need all that.  All you need is to read in an array of bytes (the contents of the file) and turn that into a Bitmap object.  What all that is useful for is to hold lots of images at once-  to make sure you don't use up too much RAM (MemoryCache), request them from the network more than once (FileChace), and to manage all of those (ImageLoader).  So if you want to download lots of images its useful.  For a single one its overkill.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have more than 1000 images to be parsed. So does that mean I do need all these classes?                            How about storing the images into sqlite, any ideas?

Comment: 1000 images is a lot of data.  Even if they're only 60K each (and that's a small image) that's 60M on disk-  that's approaching the limit of internal memory allowed per app, over it on some devices.  You'll need to store them on the SD card instead.  Since you're storing on the SD card, a file cache isn't needed but you will probably want a memorycache for holding them in RAM.  I also don't think I'd transfer it over json.  I'd send the URLs over json and download them via direct http.